# Expected value of $E[S_{ki}S_{kj}]$ in wishart dist

Tags: probability, distributions, expected-value, wishart-distribution

**Some details:**
We know that the Wishart distribution with $\nu$ degrees of freedom and positive definite $p \times p$ scale matrix $V$, $\mathcal{W}_p(\nu,V)$, has the pdf

$p(S|V,\nu) = \frac{|S|^{(\nu - p - 1)/2}}{2^{\nu p/2}|V|^{\nu/2}\Gamma_p(\nu/2)}\exp(-\frac{1}{2}\text{tr}(V^{-1}S))$

Draws from this distribution will be $p \times p$ positive semidefinite matrices so long as $\nu > p$, with expectation $\mathbb{E}[S]= \nu V$ and variance $\text{Var}[S_{ij}] = \nu(V_{ij}^2 + V_{ii}V_{jj})$.

If $\nu$ is integer valued, we can write a Wishart random variable as a sum of outer products of $\nu$ i.i.d multivariate Gaussian random variables:

$S = \sum_{i=1}^{\nu} \mathbb{u}_i \mathbb{u}_i^{\top} \sim \mathcal{W}_p(\nu,V)$,
where $\mathbb{u}_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,V)$.

**Question:**
Suppose $S$  is drawn from $W_p(v,V)$. I want to know the expected value of $E[S_{ki}S_{kj}]$ for $(i\neq j)$

Comment: `I want to know the covariance...` You want to know the covariance between two entries of the random scatter matrix S? That's a strange wish to me.

Comment: why? in fact i'm in middle of a question, i want to compute $E[S_{ki}S_{kj}]$ I thought if I can compute the covariance I can solve the expectation.

Comment: It is my imagination that you possibly misunderstand Whishart. Can you?? Let there be a multivariate normal population characterised by covariance matrix $V$. Then, if you want to draw a random sample sized $\nu$ from the population and compute the sample covariance matrix you do this: generate scatter matrix $S$ out of Wishart distribution with parameters $\nu,V$ and divide it by $\nu$. Here you are. The "random variable" from W. distr. is scatter matrix, not data points.

Comment: I think i got this meaning. I changed my question please let me know if there is any problem with it

Comment: Since this is the middle of a `question`, I think it well deserves a `self-study` tag.